# Adding ng-click within a tr element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In this fiddle I'm attempting to fire an alert within a <tr> element when the item is clicked :

http://jsfiddle.net/q8r4e/503/

Code :

```
<tr ng-controller="MyController" ng-click="alert()">alert
</tr>

function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.alert = function() {
        alert('here');
    };

}
```

But nothing is being fired. Is this possible within angular? The reason I'm attempting to use with <tr> is that I'm attempting to introduce AngularJS indo code base and im starting with listeners within a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues I can see, one is that you're in a tr, but your alert text is not in a td, so that would be the main one, if you fix that it should work.
Try doing this:

```
<tr ng-click="alert()"><td>alert</td></tr>
```

Here's a code demonstrating http://jsfiddle.net/6L4Kz/

Comment: Angular can picky about invalid html, good catch on the text not being in a `td`.  You may point out that it isn't necessary to place the controller on a wrapper, it could just as easily be on the tr.

Comment: I've seen a few questions about ng-repeat not working when trying to build a table and the reason sometimes is invalid html inside a tr or td or a div inside a tbody.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206641/angularjs-displaying-different-number-of-td-elems-in-each-tr-using-ng-repeat-and