# Can we add div inside table above every <tr>?

Tags: html

Hi am trying to add a div above every `<tr>` but when i look at the html console the div are showing outside the table. below is the html code.

```
<table>
  <div>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </div>
  <div>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Is this not allowed? any help would be great.

Comment: you can use <td>, <th>, <tbody> tag otherwise. check out my answer and following link.

Answer (score 68):

`<div>` tag can not be used above `<tr>` tag. Instead you can use `<tbody>` tag to do your work. If you are planning to give `id` attribute to `<div>` tag and doing some processing, same purpose you can achieve through `<tbody>` tag.
For further information visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051219/div-into-a-tr-is-it-correct)

For example:

```
<table>
    <tbody class="green">
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="blue">
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

secondly, you can put **"div"** tag inside **"td"** tag.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Further questions are always welcome.

Answer (score 9):

You can't put a div directly inside a table but you can put div inside `td` or `th` element.

For that you need to do is make sure the div is inside an actual table cell, a **td** or **th** element, so do that:

**HTML**:-

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <p>I'm text in a div.</p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

For more information :-

http://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot insert a div directly inside of a table. It is not correct html, and will result in unexpected output.

I would be happy to be more insightful, but you haven't said what you are attempting, so I can't really offer an alternative.

Answer (score 8):

You can not use  tag to make group of more than one  tag. If you want to make group of  tag for any purpose like in ajax to change particular  group or in CSS to change style of particular  tag etc. then use

Ex.

```
<table>
  <tbody id="foods">
    <tr>
      <td>Group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Group 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="drinks">
    <tr>
      <td>Group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Group 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the html tables, `<table>` tag expect `<tr>` tag right after itself and `<tr>` tag expect `<td>` tag right after itself. So if you want to put a div in table, you can put it in between `<td>` and `</td>` tags as  data.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>It works well</p>
      </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If we follow the [w3 org table reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/table.html) ,and follow the **Permitted Contents** section, we can see that the `table` tags takes `tbody`(optional) and `tr` as the only permitted contents.

So i reckon it is safe to say we cannot add a `div` tag which is a flow content as a direct child of the `table` which i understand is what you meant when you had said  above a `tr`.

Having said that , as we follow the above link , you will find that it is safe to use `div`s inside the `td` element as seen [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/td.html#td)

Answer (score 1):

A div cannot be added inside tr but there's an alternate solution here.

I tried adding a div inside ***tr*** but it seems a ***td*** should be the immediate child of a ***tr*** for it to work properly.

Adding a div inside ***td*** works fine.

I suppose you are trying to add some background or border-radius for the whole ***tr***. Here's how I achieved the similar result in my project.

**I'm using colspan and flex property to achieve that.**

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}
table{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
tr{
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
}
.flex-container .col{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- Assuming you have 4 columns -->
    <td colspan="4">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="col"> Item 1 </div>
        <div class="col"> Item 2 </div>
        <div class="col"> Item 3 </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem will happen whenever it will render on small device. Element `<div>` inside `<td>` will occurs in mobile responsive screen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You could use `display: table-row-group` for your div.

```
<table>
  <div style="display: table-row-group">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row-group">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </div>
</table>
```