# How to add <table> tag's child element <tbody>, Using Vue.js component

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I have a Vue (v2.5.16) component which uses a `<tbody>` with a repeating `<tr>` element in the template.  The component data is empty initially, and when I add data, Vue is placing the `<tbody>` and table rows above and outside the table, just after the `#clines` div.  Why?

Here is the html in question.  The component is srvaudit-table-rows, under the existing `<tbody>` tag.  The component template uses an additional `<tbody>` as its parent element.  Multiple `<tbody>` elemenets are allowed inside a `<table>` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table#3076790).

```
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="clines" class="table-responsive ctable">
                <table class="table table-sm nowrapp">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Command</th>
                            <th>Directory</th>
                            <th>Return</th>
                            <th>Pipes</th>
                            <th>When</th>
                            <th>Duration</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>time date</td>
                            <td>/root</td>
                            <td>42</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Feb 2</td>
                            <td>44s</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <srvaudit-command-list></srvaudit-command-list>  // Desired placement of component template and data.
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the component.

```
Vue.component('srvaudit-command-list', {
    template: `
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(command, index) in commands" :key="index">
                <td>{{ command.cmd }}</td>
                <td>{{ command.cwd }}</td>
                <td>{{ command.rval }}</td>
                <td>{{ command.pipes }}</td>
                <td>{{ command.begin }}</td>
                <td>{{ command.duration }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    `,
    props: ['command'],
    data() {
        return {
            commands: []
        };
    },
    mounted: function() {
        Echo.private(`session.${sid}.commands`)
            .listen('CommandReceived', (data) => {
                this.commands.push(data.command);  // Here is where it renders the component after pushing some data.
            });
    },
});
```

This is how it renders the html after pushing the new `command` to the `commands` data.

```
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="clines" class="table-responsive ctable">
                <tbody>                       // incorrect placement
                    <tr>                      // incorrect placement
                        <td>time date</td>    // incorrect placement
                        <td>/root</td>        // incorrect placement
                        <td>42</td>           // incorrect placement
                        <td>2</td>            // incorrect placement
                        <td>Feb 2</td>        // incorrect placement
                        <td>44s</td>          // incorrect placement
                    </tr>                     // incorrect placement
                </tbody>                      // incorrect placement
                <table class="table table-sm nowrapp">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Command</th>
                            <th>Directory</th>
                            <th>Return</th>
                            <th>Pipes</th>
                            <th>When</th>
                            <th>Duration</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>time date</td>
                            <td>/root</td>
                            <td>42</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Feb 2</td>
                            <td>44s</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!  I've been struggling with this for a couple days now and tried it every which way I can find on SO and in the Vue docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation or component replacement can be done only when if vue will get any `tag`, As there can't be any other tag except `table`,`tbody`,`thead`,`tr`,`td`. You can cross check by just put any tag inside table tag, without using vue, it will remove atomatically from table tag and put outside of table tag and without `table` tag it `tbody` does not display anything.

You can check [other discussion regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974573/div-inside-table) and [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440362/can-we-add-div-inside-table-above-every-tr)

Here is the solution to make insert `tbody` inside `table` tag by vue.js, with another component `base-table`

```js
Vue.component('base-table',{
 template:`<div>
   <table class="table table-sm nowrapp">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Command</th>
                            <th>Directory</th>
                            <th>Return</th>
                            <th>Pipes</th>
                            <th>When</th>
                            <th>Duration</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>time date</td>
                            <td>/root</td>
                            <td>42</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Feb 2</td>
                            <td>44s</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <srvaudit></srvaudit>
                </table>
                </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('srvaudit', {
    template: `
          <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>time date</td>
                            <td>/root2</td>
                            <td>99</td>
                            <td>8</td>
                            <td>Feb 5</td>
                            <td>55s</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>time date</td>
                            <td>/root4</td>
                            <td>101</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>Feb 25</td>
                            <td>88s</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
    `,
    props: ['command'],
    data() {
        return {
            commands: []
        };
    },
    mounted: function() {
    },
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script></script>

<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="clines" class="table-responsive ctable">
                <base-table></base-table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/xcfjthbo/41/)

Comment: My base table has existing data, though... how would I work around this issue with Vue not rendering the base table?    ...edit: figuring it out, I'll extract the base table into Vue instead of inline rendering.  Thanks!