# Angular ng-repeat with ng-if not working on tr tag

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-if

In the below `Div` i am using `ng-repeat` across some data to populate a list. while doing this i would like to NOT have a a certain `TR` tag created if it fits a certain requirement by using the `ng-if` directive on `x.Equipment_Cost_Child != 0` However regardless of the expression I can't get the `ng-if` to work properly.

How can i get it to only show the TR if `x.Equipment_Cost_Child > 0` ?

I have tried "`x.Equipment_Cost_Child > 0`" 
I have also attached the `ng-if` directly to the tr tag instead of a div tag.

what do you think?

```
<div  ng-repeat="x in reservationdata" ng-click="customerClickedEvent(x.ID)">
<table class="unit">
Item:{{$index + 1}}
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">Equipment Type: </td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">{{x.EquipmentType}}</td>           
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td style="font-weight:bold" >Equipment Count:  </td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">{{x.Equipment_Count}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td>Adult Quantity:  </td>
    <td>{{x.Equipment_Count_Adult}} Cost @ ${{x.Duration_Cost_Adult}}</td>
</tr>
<div ng-if="x.Equipment_Cost_Child != 0">        //this line doesn't work
<tr>    
    <td>Child Quantity:  </td>
    <td>{{x.Equipment_Count_Child}} Cost @ ${{x.Duration_Cost_Child}}</td>
</tr>
</div>
<tr>
    <td>Sending Letters: </td>
    <td> {{x.Equipment_Form_Status}}</td>
</tr>
    <td> Total Cost For Item: </td>
    <td> ${{(x.Equipment_Count_Adult * x.Duration_Cost_Adult)+(x.Equipment_Count_Child * x.Duration_Cost_Child)}}
```

Comment: Attaching the `ng-if` directly to `<tr>` *does* work (show how you try that if that's giving you problems).

Answer (score 1):

Use both ng-if and ng-repeat within one tag:

```
<tr ng-repeat="feature in features"
    ng-if="feature.id === 1" >
</tr>
```

Or, if you want to conditionally display some templates you may use ng-switch for example:

```
<tr
    ng-repeat="feature in features"
    ng-switch="feature.id" >
    <span ng-switch-when="1"></span>
    <span ng-switch-when="2"></span>
</tr>
```

Comment: is there a reason i can't put them in a separate tag?

Comment: Yes. Here its explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440362/can-we-add-div-inside-table-above-every-tr

Comment: Gautam that is good for the part of not using the DIV. Tell me this one. Can i use ng-if on a tr tag?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<div ng-if="x.Equipment_Cost_Child != 0">        //this line doesn't work
<tr>    
    <td>Child Quantity:  </td>
    <td>{{x.Equipment_Count_Child}} Cost @ ${{x.Duration_Cost_Child}}</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

By:

```
<tr ng-show="x.Equipment_Cost_Child > 0">
    <td>Child Quantity:  </td>
    <td>{{x.Equipment_Count_Child}} Cost @ ${{x.Duration_Cost_Child}}</td>
</tr>
```

`<div>` tag is breaking your `<tr>` list. You can use `ng-if` directly on `<tr>`.

EDIT: use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` to show/hide elements. It is much lighter weight, because `ng-if` triggers a DOM recompilation and generates a new scope.