# Add additional component to tr element in table

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a solution for this idea. (a `div` element after the `tr` element inside the `td` element), Is it possible to add an extra block to the `tr` element? When I try to add it the way I want, it is put out behind the `table` element.

[image: Additional component after tr element]

Comment: Show your code what are you trying and how its structured

Comment: No you can [not add a div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23440404/361762) directly inside a `<tr>`. You can add it inside a `<td>` or add another `<tr>` instead.