# JQuery - Dynamically created element css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a table dynamically using JQuery. But I cant able to apply css for the created table column. Here the sample link in codepen [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbqNJJ).

I want set `width:100px` for 1st column. Plese help me in this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually you can modify the way that you are defining the width of the columns, like:

```
td.time-cell{
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
td.drop{
  width: 100%;
}
```

in this way you can ensure that the first column is only 100px and the other one will expand.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEboLP

Answer (score 2):

Remove `#patientApptTable width:100%`;

```
#patientApptTable {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%; // remove this line
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Also, it is not valid to insert [`<div> into <tr>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051219/div-into-a-tr-is-it-correct).

Answer (score 0):

set the width of the column heading instead

```
#patientApptTable th:first-child{
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNzXeE