# How to append div to each tr in Polymerjs

Tags: javascript, html, templates, polymer

How can I append a `div` to each `tr`?

The following example is not working. It appends a `div` to `table`, instead of each `tr`

```
<table>
<tr repeat="{{ el in elements }}">
  <td>{{ el.name }}</td>
  <div> This tag I want to append to tr tag </div>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your second `tr` is not a closing tag i.e. `</tr>`. Might that be the problem?

Comment: I think it's not polymer issue, as I know `tr` can only have `td` or `th` direct descendant; have you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7051236/2407522) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2974609/2407522).

Answer (score 0):

This prints a lot of `<td>` but I am not sure what you are looking for. Try it

```
<table>
<tr>
    <template repeat="{{ el in elements }}">    
         <td>{{ el.name }}</td>
    </template>

    <div> This tag I want to append to tr tag </div>
</tr>
</table>
```