# <div ng-controller> not working inside table

Tags: html, angularjs

If I place the div element in the inner `<tr>` block the controller doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong here? 
I tried debugging through chrome that gets stuck at a particular index

```
            <div ng-controller="ctrl3">
                            <tr>
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="">
                                    <tbody>

                              i want to place the controller here but it doesn't show the result
                                        <tr><td align="left"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="" class="celltable">

                                                <thead>
                                                    <!--change style of column with css-->
                                                    <col >
                                                    <col >
                                                    <col >
                                                    <col >
                                                    <col >
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th colspan="1" ng-repeat="b in buildheadings" class="Header">{{b}}</th>

                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>

                                                <tbody><!--display none-->
                                                    <!--onclick-->



                                                    <tr >

                                                        <td ng-repeat="case in cases">{{case}}</td>                                 


                                                    </tr>




                                                </tbody>

                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </tr>
                    </div>
```

Here's the javascript code..

```
                <script>
                analyzer.controller('ctrl3',function($scope){

                            $scope.featureheadings=['Feature','Total','Passed','Failed','Random'];
                            $scope.buildheadings=['Build','Total','Passed','Failed','Random'];
                        });

                </script>
```

Also, can I use the same controller for separate blocks?

Comment: But if you set this to the div like in your example it works?

Comment: Yeah ,It does. ...

Comment: Does it have to be a table? Would display:table, display:table-cell, and display:table-row (in css) work?

Comment: No, that was just the first thing i could think of ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`div` tag can not be used above `tr` tag. Instead you can use `tbody` tag to do your work. If you are planning to give id attribute to div tag and doing some processing, same purpose you can achieve through "tbody" tag. Div and Table are both block level elements. so they can not be nested. For further information visit this page : [<div> into a <tr>: is it correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051219/div-into-a-tr-is-it-correct)

secondly, you can put "div" tag inside "td" tag.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In order to work with controller, Best way to put `ng-controller` with `table` tag or above `table` tag.

Hope it helps you!

Cheers!

Comment: So, if i have a <tr>Lots of blocks inside </tr> , I cannot use div for any element ?

Comment: I reckon yes, but if you want to put div for `ng-controller`, I think you can put on `tr` block also.

Comment: No, does not work, I tried. if you put multi ng-controller inside any table tag, it only works for 1 controller, not the second one. But if you remove table tag, all controller will works.

Answer (score 0):

if you put multi ng-controller inside any table, it only works for 1 controller, not the second one. But if you remove table tag, all controller will works

Answer (score -1):

There is problem in html markup. try this,

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="" ng-controller="ctrl3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1" ng-repeat="b in buildheadings" class="Header">{{b}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td ng-repeat="case in cases">{{case}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And,

```
 angular.module('AppName', []).controller('ctrl3', function($scope) {
    $scope.featureheadings = ['Feature', 'Total', 'Passed', 'Failed', 'Random'];
    $scope.buildheadings = ['Build', 'Total', 'Passed', 'Failed', 'Random'];
    $scope.cases = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
 });
```

Thanks!